# AWS Data Pipeline Support for SQL Server RDS

Tags: amazon-redshift, rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to find documentation regarding the supported data source for AWS Data Pipeline. What I need to do is export SQL Server RDS data to S3. I am finding plenty of documentation saying that Data Pipeline can use RDS as a source but every example I see is for MySQL RDS only.

Does anyone have experience with Data Pipeline and SQL Server RDS? If so, what data node do you use to connect to SQL Server RDS (e.g. MySqlDataNode, SqlDataNode)?

The end target is to move data from SQL Server RDS to AWS Red Shift.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We gave up on using Data Pipeline for this. I'd suggest using normal ETL tool for this. If you're running any Windows Servers then SSIS is probably the best choice, otherwise look into Pentaho or Talend.

Do you have any non-ASCII data? Getting the data from SQL Server's UTF16-LE into UTF8 was my biggest headache. I wrote some of the solution up on my blog (http://blog.joeharris76.com/2013/09/migrating-from-sql-server-to-redshift.html).

Answer (score 0):

Data-pipelines seems to only have built in support for MySQL RDS, still.

One option is to spin up an EMR cluster, and use sqoop. You can use sqoop to import into s3 and and load that directly into Redshift with the COPY command (or data-pipelines).

There is a data-pipelines EMRResource. You would need to create a bootstrap task that downloads and sets up sqoop on the master and fetches the relevant jdbc drivers.

Also the EMRActivity seems to want a jar file, when I'd want to just run the `sqoop` command from a shell script on the master. I'm not sure how easy that is to work around. Maybe a ShellCommandActivity with the EMRResource?